# Strange forward slash in 'clean' Laravel project

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I was developing as usual on my Laravel project tweaking with the Queue driver settings in my .env file, when all of a sudden a random forward slash appeared at the top of my project which caused some random issues. I've cleared all cache's, routes, views etc but I am still getting the strange forward slash. I even get it in the console when I run a command. [image]

Every page:
[image]

I assume its some kind of strange bug in Laravel. Hopefully someone can tell me whats the issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I dont have this in a fresh project (using `laravel new`) maybe you accidently added a slash at the start of a file somwhere?

Comment: I did not enter a slash anywhere. The routes and blade are fully commented out with only the default route left. No possibility I misplaced a '\'. Thanks tho. @RobbinBenard

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check your files in the `config` folder: `app.php`, `database.php`, ... and also `public/index.php` and look for a `\` before the `<?php` or if you closed it somewhere.

if you find nothing, lookout for an echo in those files. (on windows use grepwin for fast search)

Comment: You are a hero. I was so clueless. Found it in the Queue file *facepalm* strange it didnt gave a error. Thanks alot!

Comment: @JesseVlietveld make sure to not leave even a space character before the opening tag of php

Comment: You saved my life. Thank you!